# Nested inner hits in FreeText search use case

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I building a standard free text search on a site that sells cars.

In the search box the user can enter a search word that are passed on to the query where it is used to match both nested and non-nested properties.

I'm using `inner_hits` to limit the number of variants returned by the query (in this sample `variants` is not remove from `_source`)

When matching on a nested property `color` the `inner_hits` collection contains the correct variant as expected.

However when matching on a non-nested property `title` the `inner_hits` collection is empty. I understand why it's empty.

Can you suggest a better way to structure the query?

Another option would be to always just return at least 1 variant - but how can the be achieved?

**Mappings**

```
PUT test
{
  "mappings": {
    "car": {
      "properties": {
        "variants": {
          "type": "nested"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Insert data**

```
PUT test/car/1
{
  "title": "VW Golf",
  "variants": [
    {
      "color": "red",
      "forsale": true
    },
    {
      "color": "blue",
      "forsale": false
    }
  ]
}
```

**Query by color**

```
GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "variants",
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "variants.color": "blue"
        }
      },
      "inner_hits": {}
    }
  }
}
```

**Color query: works as expected!**

```
"hits" : [
      {
        "_source" : {
          "title" : "VW Golf",
          "variants" : [
            {
              "color" : "red",
              "forsale" : true
            },
            {
              "color" : "blue",
              "forsale" : false
            }
          ]
        },
        "inner_hits" : {
          "variants" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : 1,
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_nested" : {
                    "field" : "variants",
                    "offset" : 1
                  },
                  "_source" : {
                    "color" : "blue",
                    "forsale" : false
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```

**Query by brand**

```
GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "title": "golf"
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "variants",
            "query": {
              "match": {
                "variants.color": "golf"
              }
            },
            "inner_hits": {}
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Brand query result :-(**

```
"hits" : [
      {
        "_source" : {
          "title" : "VW Golf",
          "variants" : [
            {
              "color" : "red",
              "forsale" : true
            },
            {
              "color" : "blue",
              "forsale" : false
            }
          ]
        },
        "inner_hits" : {
          "variants" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : 0,
              "hits" : [ ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already know it but `inner_hits` returns an empty array because no nested documents matched in the nested query.

A simple solution is to change the query such that the nested query will always match. This can be done by wrapping the nested query into a `bool` query and add a `match_all` query.

If you set the `boost`  of the `match_all` query to 0, it will not contribute to the score. Consequently, if a nested document match it will be first.

Now the inner hits will not be empty, but there is a second problem, **all the documents will match**. You can either:

- set a [`min_score`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-min-score.html) with a very small value (e.g., 0.00000001) to discard document with a score of 0
- duplicate the original nested query and use a `minimum_should_match` at 2.

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            // Ensure that at least 1 of the first 2 queries will match
            // The third query will always match
            "minimum_should_match": 2,
            "should": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "title": <SEARCH_TERM>
                    }
                },
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "variants",
                        "query": {
                            "match": {
                                "variants.color": <SEARCH_TERM>
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "variants",
                        "query": {
                            "bool": {
                                "should": [
                                    {
                                        "match": {
                                            "variants.color": <SEARCH_TERM>
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        // Disable scoring
                                        "match_all": { "boost": 0 }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        "inner_hits": {}
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great - this is a possible solution to the problem

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is using a `script_fields` clause.

You would write a little script in painless that would do the following:

1. store the *List* you get from `variants` in a variable
2. then iterate over the *Maps* in this *List*
3. if the *Map* has
   `color` blue you return the *Map* . (If none evaluate to true you return an empty
   *Map*). This would create an additional field per searchresult with only those variants where the `color` is blue.

**One important drawback is that this is a very heavy operation, especially if you have many records.**

You can take this approach if it is something only you will ever do, maybe a few times a year outside peak hours. If your use case is something with regular use and to be performed by many users, I would change the mapping, return `variants` as a whole or choose some other solution.

Comment: It's a free text search and the number of documents are not trivial - so scripting is not an option. Thanks for the answer